# ruby言語でapiを使って特定のjsonの値を取得する

Tags: ruby, json, api, array

このコードを実行するとエラーになってしまします。助けてください

```
require "net/http"
require "uri"
require "openssl"
require "json"

key = ほげほげ
secret =ほげほげ

timestamp = Time.now.to_i.to_s
method = "GET"
uri = URI.parse("https://api.bitflyer.jp")
uri.path = "/v1/me/getpositions"
uri.query = "product_code=FX_BTC_JPY"

text = timestamp + method + uri.request_uri
sign = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(OpenSSL::Digest.new("sha256"), secret, text)

options = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri, initheader = {
"ACCESS-KEY" => key,
"ACCESS-TIMESTAMP" => timestamp,
"ACCESS-SIGN" => sign,
});

https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
https.use_ssl = true
response = https.request(options)

json = response.body
getpositions = JSON.parse(json)
puts getpositions["size"]
```

エラーコード↓

```
test04.rb:32:in []': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
from test04.rb:32:in <main>'
```

ちなみにjsonをする前のコードのレスポンスがこれです。これの`size`を取り出したいです。

```
[{"product_code":"FX_BTC_JPY","side":"BUY","price":321400.000000000000,"size":0.001000000000,"commission":0.000000000000,"swap_point_accumulate":0.294105200000000000000000,"require_collateral":21.426666666666666666666666667,"open_date":"2017-08-04T15:22:29.113","leverage":15.000000000000,"pnl":59.565894800000000000000000}]
```

Comment: エラーメッセージはエラーが32行目にあることを示していますが、提示されたソースコードは30行しかないですね...

Comment: ずれてました。ここが32行目です。puts getpositions["size"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

レスポンスを見てみると、配列の中にハッシュが入っている構造のデータです。
`getpositions[0]['size']`
もしくは
`getpositions.first['size']`

などで取得しましょう。

Comment: jsonの処理のところを直したのですがレスポンスが空白になってしまします。　　puts getpositions[0][:size]

Comment: なぜキーをシンボルにしているのでしょう、質問内のコードは普通に`JSON.parse(json)`しているだけなので、キーは文字列のはずです。

Comment: @timu さん、`puts getpositions[0]["size"]`ではどうなりますか?

Comment: できました！ありがとうございます！

Comment: @OOPer おっしゃる通りでした。修正しました。

Comment: @timu さん、修正されたこちらのshingo.nakanishiさんの回答はあなたのご質問にある課題を解決したことになるかと思います。課題が解決できた場合には、解決に最も役だった回答に「承認」のチェックを入れるのがこのサイトのルールです。課題解決後には必ず承認をお願いします。